# How to resolve "jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'nutrition' is undefined" error in Flask for CS50 Final Project

Tags: flask, cs50

I am getting following error when i run the flask: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'nutrition' is undefined. I tried several things but still couldn't resolve it.
Please help resolve the problem.
Code is below:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        nutrition = Recipe_nutrition(request.form.get("recipes"))
        instructions = Instructions(request.form.get("recipes"))

        return render_template("index.html", nutrition = nutrition, instructions = instructions)
    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redi)
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")
```

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Index
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
    <form action="/" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form-control" name="recipes" placeholder="Recipe" type="text" required/>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Nutrition</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Units</th>
      </tr>
    {% for keys, values in nutrition.items() %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ keys }}</td>
        <td>{{ values[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ values[1] }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Steps</th>
      </tr>
    {% for keys, values in instructions.items() %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ keys }}</td>
        <td>{{ values }}</td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Jinja template, you both access `nutrition` and `instructions`, but you only set them in case of a `POST` request.

You have several options now.

Either set both to an empty list, and also pass them into your `render_template` function for the `GET` case (your `else`branch).

Or return a different template, where nutrition and instructions are not necessary.

Maybe there is also a builtin Jinja solution, but I do not know one.

Comment: Hi, based on your suggestion i tweaked the code in my python file to as below. The older problem got resolved, however, the code is failing to deliver recipe_post.html on searching for a recipe. It still delivers recipe_get. html.

Comment: @app.route("/recipes", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def recipes():
    if request.method == "POST":
        nutrition = Recipe_nutrition(request.form.get("recipes"))
        instructions = Instructions(request.form.get("recipes"))

        return render_template("recipe_post.html", nutrition = nutrition, instructions = instructions)
    else:
        return render_template("recipe_get.html")

Comment: Karan, usually on StackOverFlow you ask a question, and when you get the correct answer, is to accept the answer and mabye upvote it - that would be super nice. It is almost impossible to read code in a comment, which is not formatted properly. Also, it is hard to follow the question if you edit the question - so the answer does not fit anymore. Please ask a new question with your new problem, show all the code and the complete error message, and I and others will try to help once again. Thanks!